# In OpenMx 2, what does Error: no slot of name "objective" for this object of class "MxRAMModel" mean?

Tags: r, openmx

In OpenMx 1, we could access the objective with

```
model@objective
```

In OpenMx 2, this slot is missing (as the objective now distinguishes explicitly between the expectation and the fit function). So, I guess we should be accessing the objective with

```
model$expectation
model$fitfunction
```

Or

```
model@expectation
model@fitfunction
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The 2.0 release note says:

> - Replacement of @ accessors with $ accessors in mxModel objects. You no
>     longer have to keep track of when to use which; just always use $!
>
> NOTE: Concerning the last bullet point, users should definitely get
>   into the habit of ALWAYS using $ instead of @. For example,
>   myModelRun@output$estimate would now be myModelRun$output$estimate. We
>   CANNOT guarantee that every usage of the @ accessor that worked with
>   versions 1.3/1.4 will continue to work in 2.0.

http://openmx.psyc.virginia.edu/2014/05/first-openmx-20-beta-released

Answer (score 0):

Yes: in OpenMx 2 the correct thing to do is `model$fitfunction` and `model$expectation`

In general, in OpenMx 2, avoid using @ to access any part of a model: Use $ instead.
Helpfully, OpenMx 2 also enables tab-completion for easy discovery of model components.